# Atribuir uma Classe C# a uma List<> C#, via código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, asp.net, nfe

Olá, desejo atribuir novas linhas de preenchimento ao pressionar um botão sem sair da pagina. Porem para isso, necessito atribuir uma nova classe.
Notei que a função C# que coloquei dentro da função JS ocorre uma única vez independente do Botão.
A função está atribuindo novas linhas, mas não está instanciando novas classes.
[image: Resultado do código completo]

```
<script>
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let linhas = document.querySelector("#novo")

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
```

*>  **@{

> ```
>         var _Detalhes = new cl_Detalhes();
>         Model.Detalhes.Add(_Detalhes);
>         int D = Model.Detalhes.Count - 1;
>     }***
> ```

```
    let item = document.createElement("tr")
    item.id = @Model.Detalhes[D].Produto.Codigo
    item.innerHTML += ' <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Detalhes[D].Produto.CodigoI, new { @class = "form-control " })</td> '
    item.innerHTML += ' <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Detalhes[D].Produto.Codigo, new { @class = "form-control" })</td> '
    item.innerHTML += ' <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Detalhes[D].Produto.Nome, new { @class = "form-control" })</td> '
    item.innerHTML += ' <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Detalhes[D].Produto.rastro[0].Quantidade, new { @class = "form-control" })</td> '
    item.innerHTML += ' <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Detalhes[D].Produto.Unidade_Medida, new { @class = "form-control" }) </td> '
    item.innerHTML += ' <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Detalhes[D].Produto.rastro[0].Lote, new { @class = "form-control" }) </td> '
    item.innerHTML += ' <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Detalhes[D].Produto.rastro[0].Validade.Date, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>'
    linhas.append(item);

        console.log( @Model.Detalhes.Count )
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: use um javascript reativo ... não é melhor?

Comment: Vou mergulhar neste assunto de javascript reativo.

Answer (score 0):

Opa Ericsson, tudo bem?

Na verdade o seu código não está funcionando pois o C# é carregado e executado do lado do servidor, e o javascript é executado do lado do cliente.
Então, quando você carrega a sua página, o C# é executado, e um item sempre será adicionado na sua lista.

Para executar uma função em C# sem recarregar a página você pode utilizar AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). Assim você pode chamar uma função no seu Controller sem recarregar a página.

Porém no seu caso, me parece que você já quer carregar o Model, certo?
Se for apenas para pegar no submit do formulário esses itens, você não precisa fazer em "tempo real", precisa apenas pegar tudo isso no seu Controller.

Caso você precise das informações em tempo real, faça um objeto com javascript e manipule ele conforme necessário.

Caso nada disso que eu falei até então resolva seu problema, me explique com mais detalhes por favor que vamos chegar em alguma solução.

Comment: Todas as informações entram por View Tipada através da classe InfNFe e suas subclasses e são submetidas para o controller por está mesma classe.

Comment: Isso funciona muito bem quando é feito o upload do xml, onde a View já é construída com as classes fixas, o problema é  o preenchimento manual onde eu não sei quantos produtos e ou Lotes o usuário irá preencher... Eu pensei em antes de entrar na View, instanciar várias classes(Detalhes) e (rastros) no controlller.